# Implying equality in a Haskell pattern match

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, boolean-logic

I'm writing a function to simplify a Boolean expression. For example, `Nand(A, A) == Not(A)`. I've tried to implement this particular rule using pattern matching, like so:

```hs
-- Operands equivalent - simplify!
simplify (Nand q q) = Not (simplify q)
-- Operands must be different, so recurse.
simplify (Nand q q') = Nand (simplify q) (simplify q')
```

Upon compiling, I get the error:

```
Conflicting definitions for `q'
Bound at: boolean.hs:73:21
          boolean:73:29
In an equation for `simplify'
```

I think I understand what's going on, and I've worked around it, but I'd just like to know:

1. Why is this sort of pattern matching not possible?
2. Is there an idiomatic workaround?

*Full disclosure: this is related to homework, but the purpose of the course is not to learn Haskell, and I've solved it my own way anyway.*

Comment: A pattern that uses a variable twice is called a non-linear pattern. There are languages that provide non-linear patterns like Erlang and I think it was a design choice to not include them in Haskell. The mailing list post http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell@haskell.org/msg03721.html contains some arguments against non-linear patterns but they are quite high-level arguments.

Comment: Note that (Nand q q') does not imply that q and q' are different. q = 3 q' = 3 (I think this is the reason for the design choise)

Comment: @Vixen, well, if the first pattern wouldn't match, it'd mean that they are different in the second pattern...

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I think that q not neccecarily == q' was the design descision behind it

Comment: @Vixen: noted! I changed the comment so it doesn't seem like `(Nand q q')` implies `q /= q'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could stick to your original style:

```
-- Operands equivalent - simplify!
simplify (Nand q q') | q == q' = Not (simplify q)
-- Operands must be different, so recurse.
simplify (Nand q q') = Nand (simplify q) (simplify q')
```

Also, I think you should simplify before equality testing and not after:

```
simplify (Nand q q') = if qs == qs' then Not qs else Nand qs qs' where
    qs = simplify q
    qs' = simplify q'
```

Comment: Good catch with the simplification before equality testing!

Answer (score 16):

The solution I've found is to use guards to check for equality of sub-structures:

```hs
simplify (Nand q q')
    -- Operands equivalent - simplify!
    | q == q' = Not (simplify q)
    -- Operands different - recurse.
    | otherwise = Nand (simplify q) (simplify q')
```

Comment: This is probably the way to do it, the problem is that you can't reuse the same pattern like you tried to do. I've done the same before, and reached basically the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

The "answer" is that you're not allowed to mention the same variable twice in a pattern. Not in Haskell, anyway. The best way to solve this is the one you appear to have already discovered - use pattern guards to test for equality or inequality.