# Why do generators overwrite variable values in Haskell list comprehension?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

Let's say we have a predefined list `pairs`, which is a list of all pairs (x,y) such that x,y∈{1..9}, and 2x=y. In Haskell it would look like:

```
pairs = [ (x,y) | x <- [1..9], y <- [1..9], 2 * x == y ]
```

Now, I want to use `pairs` to define a new list `triplets`, which is a list of all triplets (x,y,z) such that x,y,z∈{1..9}, 2x=y, and 2y=z. The obvious way to write it would be:

```
triplets = [ (x,y,z) | (x,y) <- pairs, (y,z) <- pairs ]
```

Which, strangely, does not work.

Now, I know the *technical* reason why it doesn't: The `(y,z) <- pairs` generator loops more tightly than `(x,y) <- pairs`, and the value it assigns to `y` overwrites whatever `y` was before entering that loop. But why would you design a language to do that? Wouldn't it be more intuitive (and conformant to mathematical conventions) to let generators 'see' to its left and reuse preassigned values, so that each variable would have a single value in each iteration? I think there must be a pragmatic rationale behind this design choice, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just write it as `triplets = [(x, y, z) | x <- [1..9], y <- [1..9], z <- [1..9]]`?

Comment: @AaditMShah Specifically, OP wants triplets of `(x, 2*x, 4*x)`, which should return `[(1,2,4),(2,4,8)]`.

Comment: Direct definition is easier in this case, but there are complex situations where using preexisting lists is preferable. I just chose a simple example for purposes of discussion.

Comment: what you are trying to is similar to your own version of `==` with `myEq x x = True`, `myEq _ _ = False`. This does not compile, you cannot use the same formal parameter twice. As others already answered, haskell interprets that list comprehension different than you.

Comment: indeed it is like that, in Prolog: `pair(X,Y):- between(1,9,X),between(1,9,Y),Y is 2*X. triplet(X,Y,Z):- pair(X,Y),pair(Y,Z).` does what you wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that list comprehension is just another way to write do notation for the list monad:

```
triplets = do
    (x, y) <- pairs
    (y, z) <- pairs
    return (x, y, z)
```

So instead, you see that you're rebinding a name inside a monadic action.  While this is allowed, if you turn on `-Wall`, you get the warnings

```
Warning: Defined by not used: `y'
Warning:
    The binding for `y' shadows the existing binding bound at module:line:column
```

Instead, the preferred method is to do

```
triplets = do
    (x, y1) <- pairs
    (y2, z) <- pairs
    guard $ y1 == y2
    return (x, y1, z)
```

Or as a comprehension

```
triplets = [(x, y1, z) | (x, y1) <- pairs, (y2, z) <- pairs, y1 == y2]
```

Remember the mantra "explicit is better than implicit".  You wouldn't gain any efficiency bonus from being able to do what you want to do over this, and this clearly expresses your intent while `[(x, y, z) | (x, y) <- pairs, (y, z) <- pairs]` is harder to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Operationally the best you can do anyway is somehow filter the generator

```
[ (x, y, z) | (x, y) <- pairs, (y', z) <- pairs, y == y' ]
```

or

```
[ (x, y, z) | (x, y) <- pairs, (_, z) <- filter (\(y', _) -> y == y') pairs ]
```

---

It's also useful to think of how these (straightfowardly) convert to List monad usage

```
-- [ (x, y, z) | (x, y) <- pairs, (y', z) <- pairs, y == y' ]

do (x,  y) <- pairs
   (y', z) <- pairs
   guard (y == y')
   return (x, y, z)
```

which makes the value shadowing in the first example more clear

```
-- [ (x, y, z) | (x, y) <- pairs, (y, z) <- pairs ]

do (x, y) <- pairs
   (y, z) <- pairs   -- shadows!
   return (x, y, z)
```

It's worth being a clear that while this intuition holds generally, list comprehensions are defined explicitly in the Haskell Report and thus may interact strangely with syntax overloading.

Comment: In your last example, the list comprehension should be `[(x, y', z) | (x, y) <- pairs, (y', z) <- pairs]`, since in the do-notation the `y` in `(y, z) <-` overwrites the `y` in `(x, y) <-`.

Comment: Oh, I copied and pasted the wrong list-comprehension

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this design choice must have been *consistency*:

```
g xs = [x | x <- xs, y <- xs]
```

would be of type `g :: [a] -> [a]`, as it is now, but

```
h xs = [x | x <- xs, x <- xs]
```

would have to be of type `h :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]`.

If allowing repeating pattern variables to denote equality in list comprehensions, the same would have to be allowed in functions too, with the same problem of sudden appearance of `Eq` constraint. Such *patterns* are called *non-linear* by the way.

Comparing the received arguments for equality would also alter their strictness (both would have to be forced). And we can not require the arguments to just be "the same" because of Haskell's referential transparency, whereby "pointer equality" is not defined (in other words, it must be impossible to distinguish between `x = 1; z = g x x` and `x = 1; z = g x 1`, in Haskell).

On the other hand, if the equality really is necessary, it is quite easy to add an explicit equality guard (as other answers show).

see also:

- [Implying equality in a Haskell pattern match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084593/implying-equality-in-a-haskell-pattern-match)
- http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell@haskell.org/msg03721.html