# What are nonlinear patterns

Tags: haskell, type-families

I am reading the paper about the `servant`-api DSL (see pdf [here](http://www.andres-loeh.de/Servant/servant-wgp.pdf))

Quoting from *Section 5.2 Type safe Links* (emphasize added by me)

> ```
> type family ElSymbol e (s :: Symbol) a :: Bool where
> ElSymbol (s :> e) s a = Elem e a
> ElSymbol e s a = False
> ```
>
> Note that type families in GHC – unlike normal function definitions –
>   allow **non-linear patterns**, and the double occurrence of `s` on the left
>   hand side of the first case implies that both symbols must be equal.

**What are non-linear patterns in haskell?**

The fact that both occurrences of `s` need to be equal, is clear this is a consequence of the `ScopedTypeVariables`-pragma.

I know linear/non-linear functions only from the context of mathematics where `y = kx + d` is a (1-dimensional) linear function and something like `y = x² sin(x)` would be an example for a non-linear function.

I guess the non-linearity comes from the type constructor (Quoting from *Section 3.3 Types are first-class citizens*)

> ```
> data (item :: k) :> api
> infixr 9 :>
> ```

but I cannot quite understand what makes this non-linear, and what would be an example of a linear constructor, if my guess is correct, that the constructor is introducing the non-linearity.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it just says that the pattern will only match if the symbols that are used multiple in places indeed are the same - in your *normal* pattern-matching something like `(a,a)` is not ok - you need to add a guard `(a,b) | a == b`

Comment: in the case above it means that indeed the *pattern* will match `ElSymbol (S :> E) S A` but not `ElSymbol (S :> E) T A` - what I don't know is if `S ~ T` would be fine here

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084593/implying-equality-in-a-haskell-pattern-match), in particular the first comment under the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A linear pattern is a patter where each variable appears at most one.

A non-linear pattern allows reusing the same variable name implying that all the values matched by it must be equal.

What the documentation is saying is that non linear patterns are accepted in type families definitions while they are **not** in normal function definitions:

```
Prelude> let f x x = x

<interactive>:2:7:
    Conflicting definitions for ‘x’
    Bound at: <interactive>:2:7
              <interactive>:2:9
    In an equation for ‘f’
```

There's nothing "deep" in this. There are other languages which allow "non linear" patterns in function definitions (e.g. Curry).

So: no, type constructors have nothing to do with linearity/non linerity. Is just how you use variables in the pattern matching.

---

As to why Haskell doesn't have non linear patterns for function definitions: there are cons. For example what should `\x x -> x` mean? `\x -> \x -> x`? Or `\x y | x == y -> x`?

Also `f x x = 1` would *not* be a total function. There's an hidden guard, and thus `f [1..] [1..]` would loop forever instead of simply returning `1`.

---

As has been pointed out in the comments, the *linear* term may come from [*linear logic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_logic). This logic has a ["resource interpretation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_logic#The_resource_interpretation) where, fundamentally, implication "consumes" its antecedent in order to produce the consequent.

In its sequent calculus you cannot reuse an hypothesis multiple times as you do in classical logic. This is akin to linear patterns: you cannot reuse the same variable multiple times.
<sub>Follow-up question: why is linear logic called *linear* logic? No idea.</sub>

Comment: I guess this usage of 'linear' comes from linear logic (where there are connectives that allow you to "use" a value only once as the premisse to an implication)?

Comment: @yatima2975 Yeah, it may come from that. In fact a function is quite similar to a logical implication (if you give me this [the argument], I give you that [the result]) and linear logic implication has that "resource" notion. But it's just an analogy, AFAIK Haskell and similar languages don't really have a very strict relationship with linear logic to suggest anything more than that.