# Non linear patterns in quasi-quotes

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, template-haskell, quasiquotes

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/marcin/quasiquotation-101) to implement a quasi quoted DSL, and I now want to support [non-linear patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35892473/3694032) in a quoted pattern. That will allow a repeated binder in a pattern to assert the equality of the matched data. For example, one can then write `eval [expr| $a + $a|] = 2 * eval a`. I modified `antiExprPat` as follows:

```
antiExpPat (MetaExp s) = 
  Just (do b <- lookupValueName s
           let n = mkName s
               p0 = VarP n
               p1 <- (viewP [|(== $(varE n))|] [p|True|])
           let res = case b of Nothing -> p0
                               _ -> p1
           return res)
antiExpPat _ = Nothing
```

The idea is to use [`lookupValueName`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.12.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:lookupValueName) to check if the anti-quoted name `s` is in scope. If not, then just create a binder with the same name. Otherwise, create a [view pattern](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns) `(== s) -> True` that asserts the matched data equals to the data already bound to `s`. Essentially, I want to convert the quoted pattern `[expr| $a + $a |]` to the Haskell pattern `(Add a ((== a) -> True))`.

But that didn't work. The resulting Haskell pattern is `Add a a`, which means `lookupValueName` never thinks `a` is in scope. Am I misunderstanding how `lookupValueName` works? Or is there a better way to implement non linear patterns here?

The full code is [here](https://github.com/remysucre/google/blob/master/src/JQQ.hs) if you want to play with it. In short, I'm making a quasi quoter to match on Java source.

---

**Update 1:**

As @chi pointed out, `lookupValueName` only checks for the splice's *context*, whereas I need to check for the splice's *content*. Any idea how to proceed with that?

---

**Update 2:**

So I bit the bullet and threaded the set of in-scope names with a state monad, and traversed the parse tree with [`transformM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate-1.6.12/docs/Data-Generics-Uniplate-DataOnly.html#v:transformM) which replaces every in-scope meta-variable `x` with `((== x) -> True)`:

```
dataToPatQ (const Nothing `extQ` ...) (evalState (rename s) DS.empty)
...
rename :: Language.Java.Syntax.Stmt -> State (DS.Set String) Language.Java.Syntax.Stmt
rename p = transformM rnvar p
  where rnvar (MetaStmt n) = do s <- get
                                let res = if DS.member n s 
                                          then (SAssertEq n) 
                                          else (MetaStmt n)
                                put (DS.insert n s)
                                return res
        rnvar x = return x
```

It got the right result on the inputs I have, but I have no idea if it is correct, especially given `transformM` traverses the tree bottom-up so inner meta-variables may be added to the set first.

Comment: I think `lookupValueName` considers variables in scope just _outside_ the splice, and not the ones which are being defined within the pattern. E.g. `eval (Add x [expr| ... |]) = ...` can see `x`. You'll have to find the variables defined _within_ the pattern-sllice on your own.