# Haskell - How to get type signature "a -> a -> a"?

Tags: haskell, types, signature

This question is based on an exercise question in the book "Haskell Programming from first principles".  It's for helping us understand parametricity.

How do we get type signature `a -> a -> a`?  The book states that there are only 2 type signatures that work.

I've tried these, but they all failed:

`test1 a a = a` 
ERROR - Repeated variable "a" in pattern

`test1 = \ a -> a -> a`
ERROR - Syntax error in input (unexpected `->')

`test1 _ a = id a` 
wrong result: `test1 :: a -> b -> b`

`test1 a = id a . id a`
wrong result: `test1 :: (a -> a) -> a -> a`

`test1 a b = a + b`
wrong result due to the `Num` type constructor: `test1 :: Num a => a -> a -> a`

Comment: One note about `test1 a a = a`. You are naming both arguments `a`. One could interpret it as saying "this is a partial function that, when the two arguments are *exactly* the same, it returns the argument, otherwise gives an error". In Haskell those kinds of patterns are forbidden *at the term level*. They are allowed at the type level though, in function-like "type families" that transform types into other types (instead of terms into other terms) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35891663/what-are-nonlinear-patterns They are called "non-linear patterns".

Comment: ``foo1 x y = (y `asTypeOf` x) `seq` x`` ; ``foo2 x y = (y `asTypeOf` x) `seq` y`` . `foo3 x y = [x,y] !! 0` ; `foo4 x y = [x,y] !! 1` .

Comment: I would advise you to get more thoroughly familiar with Haskell syntax and wiring Haskell functions before tackling parametricity exercises.

Comment: @WillNess: Thanks, all 4 of your solutions worked!

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't know anything about the type `a`, the only two functions that can have type signature `a -> a -> a` are:

```hs
someFunc  a b = a

-- and

someFunc2 a b = b
```

Being unable to operate on the values, the only valid returns are either the first argument or the second one.

---

As an interesting note, you can write this without referencing `b` at all.

```hs
someFunc    = const
someFunc2 _ = id
```

Comment: As an aside, HPFFP is an excellent read and I've strongly recommended it to a number of colleagues. Great purchase :)

Comment: @Adam: I tried what you suggested and got this in return from my installation of HUGS: `someFunc :: a -> b -> a`.  Could HUGS be unsuitable for testing type signatures?

Comment: @maxloo: ... but there are only two functions that can be defined with type signature `a -> a -> a`, that is, after a declaration `f :: a-> a -> a` there are just two functions `f` that can possibly be defined. Both have a more general type as well. Functions usually have many types, but there can be only one _most general_ type.

Comment: @HansLub: Thanks, I think I get it.  I tried to force the type signature with a `someFunc :: a -> a -> a` along with `someFunc a b = a` and it worked.  :)

Comment: @AdamSmith `someFunc = const`